# problem in backuping my database in my disk

Tags: mysql

C:\Users****>mysqldump -u*** -p**** testdb > C:\backup\testdb.sql
'mysqldump' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

explain me how can i execute the command in tha command prompt;